# Why isn't my EventHandler firing? (Asp.Net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am programatically making some LinkButtons, and they worked fine for a while, but now the events aren't firing and I can't figure out why?

This is what makes the button:

```
protected void MakeUploadButton(attachment a, PlaceHolder ph)
{
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton()
    {
        Text = "Upload New " + a.attachment_type.type_name,
        CssClass = "button right",
        ID = "lb" + a.attachment_type.file_tag,
        CommandArgument = a.attachment_type_id.ToString(),
        CommandName = a.attachment_type.type_name,
        CausesValidation = false
    };
    lb.Click += new EventHandler(showModalPopup);
    lb.DataBind();
    ph.Controls.Add(lb);
}
```

**ShowModalPopup** exists and all, but when I run it in Debug, nothing inside of it ever fires... for some reason, it is not getting called.  Any ideas?

---

found my answer here:
http://bytes.com/groups/net-asp/329287-linkbutton-event-not-firing

Comment: Does the page post back on the click of the LinkButton? Or is there no post back at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because .NET nukes an elements event handlers on postback if they aren't set in viewstate. All you need to do is re-attach the eventhandler in the onload event.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   If Page.IsPostBack Then
      Dim lb as ListButton = TryCast(Page.FindControl("IDOfControl"), LinkButton)
      lb.Click += new EventHandler(showModalPopup);
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you create your controls on every page cycle (postback too). This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) gives a good overview to the ASP.NET page life cycle.

> **Catch-up Events for Added Controls**
>
> If controls are created dynamically at
>   run time or are authored declaratively
>   within templates of data-bound
>   controls, their events are initially
>   not synchronized with those of other
>   controls on the page. For example, for
>   a control that is added at run time,
>   the Init and Load events might occur
>   much later in the page life cycle than
>   the same events for controls created
>   declaratively.
>
> Therefore, from the
>   time that they are instantiated,
>   dynamically added controls and
>   controls in templates raise their
>   events one after the other until they
>   have caught up to the event during
>   which it was added to the Controls
>   collection.